# Mismatch in the name

Tags: passports

My passport has the name "Apoorva Soorya Chandrashekar Shekhar." However, on my boarding pass, it says "Apoorva Aoorya Chandrasekhar."  I am traveling on a domestic flight; will this be a problem?

Comment: You should be okay, your name is really long and I'm sure they understand. 3 out of 4 parts are present which should be a close enough match.

Comment: To others: don't VTC as duplicate yet. Writing about it on meta.

Comment: It is already happened with may name. I have two surnames and sometimes, they put my first surname together my first name. I sure that you will not have problem.

Answer (score 1):

So, if I understand you right, they did two mistakes:

- missing second family name (Shekhar)
- misspelled your (second) first name (Soorya -> Aoorya)

The missing family name is usually no problem at all, as long as any travel document you use (personal identification such as your passport) shows both names (has to mention the name which is shown on the ticket).

Regarding the misspelled first name it really depends. Usually, a simple "typo" as in your case is no problem at all. To be on the safe side I always suggest to simply get in contact with the company you are travelling with and confirm with them. But in my experience a typo is really no problem.

If your name showing on the ticket was completely different (Anna instead of Soorya), then it would most probably be difficult to explain. And the ticket could indeed be from a completely different person (which is the reasoning for having the name on the ticket in the first place, to make sure it is the intended person travelling, and not someone else).

So, to summarize:

- missing family name: no problem at all.
- typo in first name: should be no problem either.

Suggest to confirm with the airline. ;-)